# Turn string vector with empty elements into joined string vector

Tags: string, vector, rust

I have a `Vec<&str>`, containing empty strings. I'd like to write a function `join_and_partition_on_empty`, that returns a `Vec<&str>` where all the non-empty strings are joined with a space and the empty strings are removed, creating new string starts.

```rust
// example test
assert_eq!(
   join_and_partition_on_empty(vec!["a", "", "b", "c", "", "d", "e" ],
   vec!["a", "b c", "d e" ]
)
```

I have tried using an iterator and `fold`, but ran into ownership problems when trying to concatenate strings.

Comment: You can't return a `Vec<&str>` since you have to create new data, so you should return a `Vec<String>` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the following meet the requirements?

```rust
let input = vec!["a", "", "b", "c", "", "d", "e"];
let res = input
    .split(|s| s.is_empty())
    .filter(|s| !s.is_empty())
    .map(|s| s.join(" "))
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

```rust
["a", "b c", "d e"]
```

If required, one can use [`filter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter) to remove extra sub-slices that result due to contiguous empty strings. The input below will produce the same output as listed above:

```rust
let input = vec!["a", "", "", "", "", "b", "c", "", "d", "e"];
```

The above *might* not be as efficient, as the docs for [`.split()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split) mention that sub-slices are created for each element that matches the predicate, i.e. empty strings.

As an alternative, here's an imperative method that might be more performant due to ignoring empty strings:

```rust
let input = vec!["a", "", "b", "c", "", "d", "e" ];

let mut res = vec![];
let mut group = vec![];

for s in input.iter() {
    if !s.is_empty() {
        group.push(&s[..]);
    } else if !group.is_empty() {
        res.push(group.join(" "));
        group.clear();
    }
}

// Push any remaining values
if !group.is_empty() {
    res.push(group.join(" "));
}
```